# Python total sum from a csv file

Tags: python, r, excel, database, csv

i have 133 CSV files

the first file file1.cvs 
have the following data :

```
A               b    C
Name            2   Value
jack            3   2%
jack            3   1.33%
jack            4   1.112%
sara            5   4%
sara            6   9%
adam            1   7%
adam            2   10%
nada            3   3%
nada            4   1%
tom             5   1%
```

i want to Calculate the sum of specific name on the column (jack,sara,tom only ) and C column ,and save the output on new csv file that look like :

```
File name : file1.csv
jack  4.442%
sara  13%
tom   1%    

File name : file2.csv
```

.......etc

using any programming language ( python , ruby , r etc.. )

Comment: try pandas read_csv I guess

Comment: Using `python` will probably be very easy to get it done, and specifically the `pandas` module with `DataFrame` capabilities. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

1.Create reproducible minimal example data

```
df <- data.frame(A=rep(c("Jack", "Joe"), 3), C=runif(6))
```

2.Solution using `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)
summarised <- df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(C))

write.csv(summarised, "File_Name.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `R` you could first search for all the csv contained in one folder and then do an `sapply` over that vector (using `dplyr` package to perform the desired operations). Finally, search for the results files in the same folder indicated in `list.files`.

```
library(dplyr)

#Find all the csv files in the indicated path
#Change the path location to the folder where you have your csv files
file_locs<-list.files(path="C:/Folder with csvs",
                      pattern = ".csv",
                      full.names = T)

sapply(file_locs, function(x){

  #Read csv, skipping first line if it contains the A, b, c entries
  #as headers, if not you can remove the "skip = 1"
  df<-read.csv(x, skip = 1)

  #Use dplyr to get the Value sum, grouped by Name
  resuls<-df %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarize(sumVal = sum(Value))

  #Get the csv original name, i.e., without the .csv part
  file_name<-strsplit(x,".csv")[[1]][1]

  #Write the results using the original file name and adding: _resul
  write.csv(resuls, paste0(file_name,"_resul.csv"),row.names = F)
})
```

Comment: By the look of your file you should set `skip = 2` in the read.csv part, so it skips the first two lines of your file. Then, you should change the vars `Name` and `Value` for actual names of your data, for example, `Node.Name` and `Virtual.Memory`. You can check how `R` imports the column names of your data by using `colnames(df)`.

Comment: thank you 
I just need to find solution today sorry for asking a lot :(

i got this error now :
> source("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\12.R")
Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Probably it is caused by the fact that your data has the "%" sign. You can remove it prior to creating the resuls object, using the `stringr` package with something like: `df$Value<-str_extract(df$Value,"(\\d)+")`.